# How to identify customers based on a criteria

Tags: powerbi

I am very new to Power BI and I need help please in trying to identify certain customers based on set logic, I just don't know how best to do this. Below is a case statement from SQL to try and hopefully explain what I am trying to achieve, but I haven't ever written DAX or no enough about Power BI should there be a better way to identify these group?

when  left(bt_type,3) in ('RRR','TTT') and bt_type in ('RT12')  then 'Test_Group_One'

when bt_typein ('RT12') and  left(bt_type,3) not in ('RRR','TTT') then 'Test_Group_Two'

else 'Exclude'

end as 'Test_Type'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below **Measure** Code-

```
Test_Type = 
IF(
    (left(bt_type,3) = "RRR" || left(bt_type,3) = "TTT") && bt_type = "RT12",
    "Test_Group_One",
    IF(
        bt_type = "RT12" && (left(bt_type,3) <> "RRR" && left(bt_type,3) <> "TTT"),
        "Test_Group_Two",
        "Exclude"
    )
)
```